# Generating user profiles with request.user rather than id in url

Tags: django

I am creating user profiles using Django 1.8.

The way I have currently got it is the 'my_profile' view will use `request.user()` at the top of the view and then generate the information required from there.

My question is weather this is a bad practise for creating profiles.

In the past I have passed the user ID into the URL to create a profile but as it stands I think the `request.user()` method seems more secure and easier.

Are there any negative implications in creating it like this such as speed issues etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you will never be able to view another users profile if you do not use their ID in the URL to generate the view.

However, there is no reason why there would be any negative implications such as speed etc. by designing your user profile in this way.

I would personally recommend against it as it will limit the possibilities of what you can achieve with the user profiles.

And in terms of security, you could just add a check around the user profile view to check the current user has permission to be there.

Comment: Thanks again, I just wanted to clarify what I was doing wasn't ridiculous. I should have mentioned that the user profiles I am, creating meant to be only view-able by the person whos profile it is.